# How do I extract an individual number from a float

Tags: javascript, floating-point, extract

I need to extract individual numbers from a float without turning the float into a string but have no idea how to do that. I'm thinking of something like substr. but for a number.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you need to obtain? Do you need to isolate a digit?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I need. Say I have the number 14. I want to extract the 1 and the 4 so I can add those two together.

Comment: Why do you need to do this without converting to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can make into a string extract the number you want and then turn the string back into a number using the Number() method.

Comment: he says he doesn't want to convert it into a string.

Comment: But he can turn it back into a number with Number() after so it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Let say that you have a float like this:

```
x = 45783.7304
```

and we need the figure of hundredths

```
n = 0.01

result = Math.floor(x / n) %  10
```

if you need the digit of the thousands:

```
x = 45783.7304
n = 1000
result = Math.floor(x / n) %  10
```

Or you can split the different digits into an array (but you have to resort to strings):

```
digits = x.toString().replace(".","").split("").map(Math.floor)
```

Comment: For `x` = 0.0299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875, this reports the second digit after the decimal point digit is 3, but it is 2.

Comment: Note that because of floating point roundoff errors, this might not produce the same digits after the decimal point as converting to a string,

Comment: You can't store such a number in a float. After the assignment x value is 0.03. It is inherent to the discrete math computer uses. Since specifications state that you have to retrieve a digit from a float when you retrieve it you get a 3.@EricPostpischil

Comment: @Eineki  0.0299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875 is the exact decimal representation of nearest IEEE 754 double precision floating point to 0.03

Comment: @aka.nice Maybe I had to explain better what I was meaning. Since the [Number Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) in javascript holds 17 decimal places of precision, wile being treated internally ls a double float, you have to round it and it is reduced to 0.03. Hence, you can not hold that number in a javascript numeric object.
Maybe this limit is just the Mozilla implementation of the  language, since I've not found this limitation in the ecma script specification, though.

Comment: @Eineki Hmm, that's common miss-interpretation of the 17 decimal places... If it prints as 0.03 (the shortest decimal representation rounding to same float), it does not mean that it stores 0.03 internally. Internal representation is using base 2 (significand bits represent 2^-5, 2^-6, etc...) and 0.03 is NOT representable with such base 2 floating point.

Comment: 17 decimal places is about precision: it means that providing more digits beyond that limit won't change the resulting float, it does not mean that the float retains 17 decimals, the float does not use a decimal representation in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is already quite ill-defined if you are thinking of decimal representation of a binary-based floating point number, even if resorting to string representation, because you have several ways of printing a decimal representation of a float, like:

- the exact decimal representation of a float
- the shortest decimal representation of a float that would get interpreted back to the same float in a round-trip conversion
- some approximate decimal representation of a float rounded (or truncated, or ...) to a fixed number of digits/or decimal places.

Let's take an example, say you start with the nearest float to 0.0012345

- the exact representation of that float in IEEE 754 double precision is 0.0012344999999999999203137424075293893110938370227813720703125
- the shortest decimal representation converting back to same float - assuming round to nearest, tie to even default rounding mode - is 0.0012345
- rounded or truncated to 6 decimal places after the decimal point (4 significant digits) lead to 0.001234

But let's take the nearest float to 0.012345

- the exact decimal representation of that float is 0.01234500000000000007049916206369744031690061092376708984375
- the shortest is 0.012345
- the truncated to 5 places is 0.01234
- the rounded to 5 places is 0.01235

We see that depending on the chosen string representation, your result may slightly vary.

Without resorting to string representation, things are getting worse, because every operation that you will perform with the floating point arithmetic unit will round the result to nearest floating point, and thus may induce some slight differences in the digits. Even worse if you would think of chaining several of these inexact operations !

For example, using shortest decimal representation for the sake of brievity, the most trivial chaining gives:

```
0.0012345 * 1000000 -> 1234.5
0.0012345 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 -> 1234.4999999999998
```

The exact value of those operations, 1234.4999999999999203137424075293893110938370227813720703125 is of course not representable as a float, the nearest float being 1234.5 (exactly).

The easiest thing you could think of is converting the float to some exact decimal of binary fraction ASAP and then operate on those numbers - it's pretty sure that you will find dedicated javascript libraries to do so. But think twice on what you exactly want first, because mixing float and decimal representation is a recipe for getting surprising (unexpected) results, unless greatest care is taken !

Depending on your purposes, you may as well want to completely avoid using float representation.